# Set maximum length for a String inside an array? (Using try-catch)

Tags: java

I recently posted about a school project im working on and received a lot of help. Im still working on this and I've encountered a new issue: **I ask the user to input the name of a school subject, but I need it to be from 1 to 15 characters max, if he were to input more than 15 characters, the result I want to print would not be what I expect as I already have thought of the design.** Tried using **if(mystringarray[arrayname]>15)** but I know this is meant for Integers. Any help would be appreciated, im willing to learn.

```
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    String arrayer[] = new String[z];
    for(multi=0; multi<arrayer.length; multi++){

            do{
            out.print("\n");
            out.print("Introduzca el nombre de la materia "+(multi+1)+" : ");
            try{
                arrayer[multi]=LeerTeclado.nextLine();  
                if(arrayer[multi]>15){
                    out.println ("\nSubject name should be shorter than 15 characters\n");
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                out.println("Subject name should be shorter than 15 characters\n");
                LeerTeclado.next();
            }
        }while(true);   



    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class has [`length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String has a method for fetching length use

```
if(arrayer[multi].length() > 15)
```

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to ask for the length of the `String`

```
if(arrayer[multi].length() > 15)
```

Comment: For strings `length()` is a method.

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks for catching that. I have been programming a lot of Scala these days and the parans are optional, so it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use `arrayer[multi].length()` to get the length of the String